# (92) The gateway no longer supports the requested method of integration. AuthorizeNet

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am integrating my site with authorize payment gateway with SIM . It is giving me error as follows

```
(92) The gateway no longer supports the requested method of integration.
```

my arguments are as follows

```
x_show_form : PAYMENT_FORM 
x_delim_data : FALSE 
x_relay_response : False 
x_login : <snip> 
x_tran_key : <snip>
x_method : CC 
x_type : AUTH_CAPTURE 
x_amount : 100.00 
x_currency_code : USD 
x_invoice_num : 781 
x_test_request : TRUE 
x_receipt_link_method : POST 
x_receipt_link_text : Please return to MobiVite to complete the order and mark order successfull 
x_receipt_link_url : http://192.168.1.30:8012/mobivite/order/callback/authorizenet 
x_first_name : vaibhav 
x_last_name : Saxena 
x_company : 
x_city : delhi 
x_state : 
x_zip : 250002 
x_phone : 9310974585 
x_cust_id : 4 
x_email : vaibhav1407@gmail.com 
x_address : test 
x_country : IN
```

please help

Comment: thanks for telling us your api login and key

Comment: I see you're already being helped at the [Authnet site](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/SIM-Method-92-The-gateway-no-longer-supports-the-requested/td-p/8434)

Comment: ya john. Sorry for that. If some one needs help go to http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/SIM-Method-92-The-gateway-no-longer-supports-the-requested/td-p/8434

Comment: I already know that i shared the api login and key but it was wrong. I deliberately added a wrong key just to clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur for several possible reasons, depending on which Application Programming Interface (API) your software uses to connect to your Authorize.Net account. Usually it is due to mixing methods between our APIs.

If this is AIM , 1. If you are posting via AIM to our secure site directly from an HTML page you will receive this error. When using AIM to integrate with Authorize.Net, the post must be made from a script running in a secure location on your server, and not through an HTML page.

Be sure that your account settings are set to allow delimited responses.

Confirm that you are posting the variable x_delim_data in your script, and that it is set to "TRUE".

Also confirm that you are sending the variable x_relay_response with a value equal to "false" in your post to Authorize.Net. If you are not sending this variable and have any default relay or receipt links listed in your Response/Receipt URL settings, you will receive an Error 92.